# Using Xpath to scrape links and descriptions from this Etsy product listings page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to scrape all the links on https://www.etsy.com/market/happiness_bracelet and then the product descriptions from within each link extracted.

I am using a chrome extension called Scraper to input the xpath, obtained from right-clicking the element in Chrome Dev Tools. But not getting the desired result.

Problem: Can't find proper xpath for the links. What would be the proper setup to get the xpath of the links on that webpage and extract the product descriptions from within them?

Is there's a way to do it just using Chrome Dev Tools and the proper Xpath,  or would I need Python/bs4/selenium for this task?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

With following XPath expression in Chrome Devtools you get all the p tag elements with the product descriptions:

```
//div[contains(@class,'v2-listing-card__info')]/div/p[contains(@class,'body')]
```

See the image with the results:

[image]

Her you find the C# code to get the first line of text ('Handmade item') from the Overview paragraph for the first bracelet.

```
        // Go to the webpage
        Driver.Url = "https://www.etsy.com/market/happiness_bracelet";
        // Get all the links 
        IList<IWebElement> searchResults = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[contains(@class,'listing-link')]"));
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var result in searchResults)
        {
            i++;
            if (i > 5)
            // For all links except the first 5 hidden links
            {
                // Click the link to go to the page with information of the bracelet
                result.Click();
                // Write the first line of text of the Overview paragraph to the consol
                Console.WriteLine(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("item-overview")).FindElement(By.XPath(".//li")).Text);
                // More code needed here to pick the other information you needed 
            }             
        }
```

Comment: Okay, I have saved them in a list. What do you mean by "loop over the elements" and  ".text on the element"? The product descriptions I am referring to are the "Overview" "Shipping and "Returns" and "Descriptions' sections within the links to the products.   What do I loop

Comment: Now I understand that you need the information on the page reached after clicking the link.For this you need the anchor tags. You can use the following XPath for it: //a[contains(@class,'listing-link')]

Comment: I added some code to explain what I meant with 'loop over the elements'.

Comment: I don't understand the code at all. Can you explain where I input the url's to get the desired result? I would like  "Overview" "Shipping" and "Returns" "Descriptions" sections from within each link on that product listing page.

Comment: This example code is about getting the descriptions under the Images on the searchresult page, because I initially thought you were looking for these descriptions. You can get the url's by replacing the XPath in the code example with the XPath I gave you in my earlier comment. Next, in the code example you have to replace .Text by .Click() to go to the page you are looking for.These are just indications to reach your goal, obviously more code is needed to finish the job.

Comment: @sam9750, changed the code so the first line of text of the Overview paragraph of the first bracelet is printed.

Comment: Frank, I'm still not understanding. I have the url's now but could you give a step-by-step example on how to use the C# code for the specific webpage I am looking at: https://www.etsy.com/market/happiness_bracelet

Comment: I try to explain how to get the information you are looking for.This information is not on the searchresult page but on the pages behind the links. So you have to click these links one by one and scrap the information from the individual pages. With a little bit of experience in coding you can extend it yourself to get all the information you need, this example is only getting the first line of text of the Overview paragraph of every bracelet. I understand from your initial question that you're coding in Python, so translate it to Python and put it in the Testframework you are using.